# How can host access the files on guest on VM?

Tags: virtualbox

How can I set up VM so that the host can access the files on the guest as if the files on guest are on the hard-drive of host?

Comment: What OS is host, guest A, and guest B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share a folder within your network using samba.
you can share files with `ftp`/`http` servers like `Xampp` on your real machine and access them in virtual machine or reverse. 
You can share a folder using virtualbox `share folder` feature, if you use `shared folder` with virtual box feature, then you can access it with a samba client within virtual machine. you must try to access `vboxsvr`.